# Iterate an operation on a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
result = {
    'mary': [1, 2, 3, ''],
    'anna': [7, 9, 8],
    'liz': [2, 1, '', ''],
}
```

I want to delete all `''` from all items and save the new version of dictionary. I am trying this:

```
token = ()
for key, value in sorted(result.items()):
         token = (key, [item for item in value if item])
print(token)
```

But it only runs once through the dictionary and returns just the first line. I know this is very basic, but I am new to Python (as you can tell). Could anyone help me on how to correct that?

Comment: I've edited your sample dictionary to be valid python; can you please verify that this is what you have?

Comment: Thank you Martin, the dictionary is valid, I have worked with it already in other operations, but I put here a wrong abridged version. Thank you for correcting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary and list comprehension combined:

```
result = {key: [v for v in value if v != ''] for key, value in result.items()}
```

This creates a new dictionary with each key and value copied, but the values filtered to only contain values that are not empty strings:

```
>>> result = {
...     'mary': [1, 2, 3, ''],
...     'anna': [7, 9, 8],
...     'liz': [2, 1, '', ''],
... }
>>> {key: [v for v in value if v != ''] for key, value in result.items()}
{'liz': [2, 1], 'mary': [1, 2, 3], 'anna': [7, 9, 8]}
```

If you are using Python 2, you may want to use `result.iteritems()` instead for a more efficient loop.

Your loop was almost there, you just forgot to assign back to a dictionary:

```
for key, value in result.items():
   result[key] = [v for v in value if v != '']
```

Comment: This is perfect. I will accept in one minute! although I have to study it to understand it, it works!

Comment: I deleted my answer - I read the question incorrectly. Martijn correctly uses a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your solution is that you never assign your list comprehension to a key in a new dict. You would need to change your solution to something like:

```
new_dict = {}
for key, value in result.items():
    new_dict[key] = [item for item in value if item != '']
print(new_dict)
```

Martijn Pieters' answer, which uses dictionary comprehensions, is concise and Pythonic. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for more information about dict comprehensions.